# Read SQL Server stored procedure parameters and generate UI at runtime so as to call that stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Microsoft provides Data Connection Dialog UI nuget package which basically provides standard UI to connect to SQL Server: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/

I am wondering if there is any nuget package something like `DataConnectionDialog` which also provides standard UI interface for invoking a stored procedure from a C# app. Or is it possible to invoke some of the components in SQL Server Management Studio like SQL query analyzer directly from C# apps?

I want to add UI in my C# application which basically allows the user to input parameters and invoke few stored procedures. But I don't want to design Winforms UI for each stored procedure. Sometimes stored procedure parameters change and I will also have to change UI. I want something flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by getting the stored procedure schema from database then create textbook for each parameter with styleid, classid, or name of the parameter.
it goes as following

```
//Get the list of params first.
StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
foreach(var param in params)
{
   TextBox box = new TextBox(){Name = param.Name};
   stk.Childeren.Add(box)
}
```

and then retrieve the data as following:

```
//Write you sql command
foreach(TextBox box in stk.Childeren)
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add($"{box.Name}", SqlDBType.nvarchar).value = box.text;
}
```

hope that you find this helpful - don't forget to mark it as answer if it solved your problem.